# PineScript - Strategy.exit not responding

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v4

I have some issues with the strategy.exit. It does not work. As shown in the picture below, both exit arguments should have worked!

[image]

RSI Script:

```
// RSI parameters
var RSI = "RSI"
overBought = input(title="OverBought RSI",group=RSI, defval=75)
overSold = input(title="OverSold RSI",group=RSI, defval=20)
rsi50 = input(50,title="RSI average",group=RSI)
rsi14exit = input(title="RSI 14 OverSold Exit Strategy", group=RSI, defval=70)

// RSI Short/Long
rsiLong = rsi(close,6) <= overSold
rsiShort = rsi(close,6) >= overBought
rsiBelowAverage = rsi(close,6) <= rsi50
rsi14_exit = rsi(close,14) >= rsi14exit

// Calculating
MACD Script:
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? sma(src, fast_length) : ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? sma(src, slow_length) : ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? sma(macd, signal_length) : ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal

// MACD Long/Short
Macd_long = macd >= signal
Macd_short = macd < signal

// Strategy close
strategy.exit("LongA Closed","LongA", loss=longStop, when= Macd_short or rsi14_exit)
```

Comment: Next time please copy your full code from beginning to the end. Including `//@version=4` etc. And also, please use code sample button `{}` and wrap your code with it.

Comment: What is `longStop`? I don't see any definition for that variable in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to close a trade, so use `strategy.close()` instead.

```
strategy.close(id="LongA", when= Macd_short or rsi14_exit)
```

You can add your stop loss parameter to your `strategy.entry` call. It has a `stop` parameter.

Comment: okay, but can you explain the difference between strategy.close vs strategy.exit apart from the fact that you can add more parameters in strategy.exit. Because I get different results when I use strategy.exit and when I use it strategy.close.

Comment: Use `strategy.close()` if you want to use a **market order** to exit a specific entry of a position. Use `strategy.exit()` if you want to use a **stop** or **limit order** to exit a position. You can read [this](https://backtest-rookies.com/2019/03/01/tradingview-strategy-close-strategy-close_all-vs-strategy-exit/).